# Is every ideal class represented by a prime?

Tags: number-theory

Suppose $K$ a number field. Does every element of the class group $C_K$ have a prime ideal in its class? More generally, is this true for ray class groups?

Comment: In brief, "yes": this is the immediate generalization of Dirichlet's theorem to (Hecke...) characters on _finite_ generalized class groups and their $L$-functions. For this case of _finite_ families, simply the non-vanishing of all the relevant $L$-functions at $1$ is sufficient, and more serious arguments (Tauberian theorems) are not needed. So I should ask in what context you need clarification.

Comment: The reason I care is: in class field theory, for an unramified extension L/K the Artin map C_K->Gal(L/K) has the property that the ramification index of a prime p is the order of its image in Gal(L/K), so split primes get killed. But I want to argue further that the kernel is generated by the split primes, which would follow from the fact I asked about. Maybe there is a cheaper way?

Comment: Related: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/27308. In fact, the set of prime ideals of $O_K$ in a given ideal class of the class group $C_K$ is a set of positive natural density $1/|C_K|$. (See the comments [there](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1616908/) and Narkiewicz, Elementary and Analytic Theory of Algebraic Numbers, corollary 6 from §7.2, page 346 (notations on page 93).).

Comment: Typically, a prime $p$ of $O_K$ is principal iff it splits in the Hilbert class field $H_K$, and the density of such primes is $1/[H_K : K] = 1/|C_K|$ ; thus the class of $O_K$ contains infinitely many primes (those primes are the principal primes).